# Why am I not able to override CRUD template when using @CRUD.For?

Tags: playframework

I'm reading [the play tutorial](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/guide7) and to spice things up a little bit I decided to use @CRUD.For instead of using the default model name pluralized. The problem is that I'm trying to override the template of that model and, using @CRUD.For, it just doesn't seem to work. However, when I use the default name it just works...

I have: 
1) Model in
app/models/Comment
2) Admin class extending CRUD annotated with @CRUD.For(Comment.class)
app/controllers/admin/AdminComments 
3) I have the file
app/views/AdminComments/list
4) I'm using the command: 
play crud:ov --template AdminComments/list

Then I check the admin area and nothing... As I said, when I use the default name Comments it works.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading the information on `CRUD.For` on the play documentation, I can't see that you are doing anything wrong. I assume that when you say you have the file `app/views/AdminComments/list` you actually mean `app/views/AdminComments/list.html`, if not then that is likely to be your problem.

Also, you have stated that you use `play crud:ov --template`, leaving this last in your list. This command creates a new file in your views area, based on the template, so that you may override it to work the way you wish. I would suggest going through it in the right order, which is

1. Create your model class
2. Create your CRUD class, with the CRUD.For annotation. Making sure you import `models.Comment`
3. run play command `play crud:ov --template AdminComments/list`
4. Edit the generated template, in `app/views/AdminComments/list.html`
5. Make sure AdminComments.java is inside `app/controllers` and that your list.thml is in `app/views/AdminComments`

Comment: yesm It was a list.html. I'm goint to try it again and will give you a feedback in a sec.

Comment: Ok... I've found the problem. The problem is that my AdminComments class is inside a sub-package called admin (controllers.admin) and, I believe, the structure in the views should have been admin/AdminComments/list.html, however, play crud:ov doesn't recognize that structure, it tries to go with admin/AdminComments.html, which obviously doesn't exist.

Comment: yes, it is usually best to keep your controllers in the controllers package, and not a sub-package

Comment: also, can you check it, I don't know whether it should be reported as a bug or it should be considered as a "feature"

Comment: I think it should be raised as a bug, because it does not say explicitly in the documentation that this is not allowed.

Comment: Do you know where should I go to alert them about it? thanks btw

Comment: Also, I believe the problem resides in the command play crud:ov --template that doesn't recognize substructures, because if you add the list.html generated in the `AdminComments` folder in the `admin/AdminComments` keeping the previous controllers.admin package. It works. Therefore. I should go with play crud:ov --template AdminComents/list and then copying the file to the desired folder...

Comment: Yes, play uses lighthouse for bug tracking... http://play.lighthouseapp.com/dashboard

Comment: I've raised a ticket there. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with the rest of your development.

Answer (score 1):

Your AdminComments class is inside a sub-package `admin` (`controllers.admin`) and not directly inside the controllers package. So you will have to create a folder named `admin` inside your views directory and move the generated file `app/views/AdminComments/list.html` into this directory. Now the file path will be `app/views/admin/AdminComments/list.html`.

This worked for me. However the crud:ov command should handle this by itself.